# run pyspark locally fails but works fine in databricks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyspark

Running this script in Databricks is absolutely fine, as it just very simply creates a spark session, connect to Azure Blob Storage and reads the file:

[image]

But I get this error when I try exactly the same code locally in VS Code, seems like it's unable to find the file in the first few lines or the error message, the rest just doesn't make sense to me. Feels like I'm missing something very obvious but can't work out what so please assist!
[image]

```
22/08/29 23:07:21 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: wasbs://test@storageaccounttommytam.blob.core.windows.net/sample_lake/Sourced/SystemA/ProductCategory/date=20220606/ProductCategory.csv.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$Secure not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:571)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$Secure not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2665)
        ... 26 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/app/src/databricks/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    execute_job(job_path="test.py", example_arg="")
  File "/workspace/app/src/databricks/main.py", line 32, in execute_job
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/app/src/databricks/jobs/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    sdf = spark.read.csv(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 410, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.csv.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$Secure not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1(DataSource.scala:747)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:745)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:571)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$Secure not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2665)
        ... 29 more
```

Comment: I had same problem as you. I manage to run spark locally using a docker container. Also you can install a virtual machine using linux in your PC to run it there.

Answer (score 0):

You error shows that you miss the class `org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem`. As you run your code locally and you're trying to access the data in Azure, you need to download the corresponding jar and add it to the config when you create your Spark application, otherwise your local spark application can't read the data in Azure.